# Storing and accessing elements to array of nested structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am a newbie to C programming,below is my piece of code where there is an issue while accessing the elements of the structure. 
The `matrix1` is an array of structure to `struct matrix`. I want to store elements for each `matrix1` like `matrix1[0], matrix1[1], ...`  which is again an array of structures inside other structure. Is there a better way to store the elements to structure. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Why can't I access the elements like `matrix1[1].One[0].ChannelPin`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char ChannelNo[2];        // "P1"
    unsigned int ChannelPin;  // 23
    char State;               // 'o'
} test;

typedef struct {
    test One[2];
    test two[2];
    test three[2];
    test four[2];
    test five;
    test six[1];
} matrix;


matrix matrix1[] = {{   {{{"P4",2,'O'},{"P4",1,'O'},{"Z",0,'Z'}},
                        {{"P4",4,'O'},{"P4",3,'O'},{"P4",5,'O'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"P1",49,'S'},{"P1",1,'G'}} },

                         { {{"P4",2,'O'},{"P4",1,'O'},{"Z",0,'Z'}},
                        {{"P4",4,'O'},{"P4",3,'O'},{"P4",5,'O'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'},{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"0",0,'0'}},
                        {{"P1",49,'S'},{"P1",1,'G'}} } }


int main() {  
    printf("%d\n",matrix1[1].One[0].ChannelPin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: Be careful with the `test.ChannelNo` field, you can't use it as a string. This is because `char` strings are really called ***null terminated** byte strings*. That *null terminated* bit means that a string for two characters needs space for a third character (the terminator).

Comment: @RohanKumar No.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your time.ChannelNo size is  declared as 2 including null terminating character.Am i wrong in understanding? Can you please tell how to store values to array of nested structure.i'll have array size of 37.i.e matrix matrix1[37], and how to access it.

Comment: If you want to include the terminator for a string like `"P4"` then you need *three* characters in the array.

Comment: As for your question, what problem do you have with the code you show? Do you get build errors? Please copy-paste them into the question body. Do you get unexpected results? Then show us the expected *and* actual results. Do you get crashes? Then use a debugger to locate them.

Comment: @RohanKumar i have a missed a bracket  and semicolon in the end of the structure declaration. It doesn't compile.

Comment: Actually all arrays are too small :)

Comment: @PeterJ one of them isn't even an array and yet is being initialised as such :O

Comment: @ChrisTurner i want only one instance of test structure so i have declared it as five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the sake of readability I would init it this way. And it works.

```
typedef struct {

    char ChannelNo[3];              //"P1"
    unsigned int ChannelPin;        //23
    char State;                     //'o'
}test;

typedef struct {

    test One[3];
    test two[3];
    test three[3];
    test four[3];
    test five;
    test six[3];

}matrix;

matrix x[] =
    {
    // [0]
        {
            .One = {
                     {.ChannelNo = "P4", .ChannelPin = 23, .State = 'o'},
                     {.ChannelNo = "P1", .ChannelPin = 98, .State = 'o'},
                     {.ChannelNo = "P0", .ChannelPin = 23, .State = 'o'},
            },
            .two = {
                    {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'd'},
                    {.ChannelNo = "P4", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'e'},
                    {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'r'},
            },
            // ......
            .five = {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'r'},
        },
    // [1]
        {
            .One = {
                     {.ChannelNo = "P4", .ChannelPin = 23, .State = 'o'},
                     {.ChannelNo = "P1", .ChannelPin = 98, .State = 'o'},
                     {.ChannelNo = "P0", .ChannelPin = 23, .State = 'o'},
            },
            .two = {
                    {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'd'},
                    {.ChannelNo = "P4", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'e'},
                    {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'r'},
            },
            // ......
            .five = {.ChannelNo = "P5", .ChannelPin = 79, .State = 'r'},
        },
    // ......
    };
```

it is faster to write than to find the missing pair of brackets or voalues :)

Comment: Despite pointing out there are too many elements for one, two etc...your example still makes that mistake?

Comment: @Chris Turner copy & paste error, forgot to select the new typedefs

Comment: this works...but if subscript is 37 i.e x[37]  then how to store and access x[1].One[0].ChannelPin  was my question.

Comment: @ChrisTurner this is the error Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
D:\EXPERIMENTS\Panel_test\test1.c|28|error: excess elements in struct initializer|
D:\EXPERIMENTS\Panel_test\test1.c|28|error: (near initialization for 'matrix1[0].One[0].ChannelNo')|

Comment: @shruthi I do not understand what you mean - it compiles and executes OK. Which answer do you comment?

Comment: @shruthi then you will have a loooooooooooong initialisation in your file.

Comment: @PeterJ sorry it was th error was the code i posted above. thank you for your valuable time.Thanks alot!

Comment: write the script which will generate the code for you if you need a static initialisation.

Comment: @shruthi think your comment about the error was meant to be on the main thread...but it's quite clearly stating the problem - you're trying to fit 3 elements into an array of 2.

Comment: @ChrisTurner yep the issue resolved. thank you for your valuable time.